# cheerio parse h2 with a href and span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

This is my html to parse:

```
      <h2 class="offer-header">

        <a class="offer-title" href="http://address.com/id/2">Item name</a>
    </h2> 

        <div class="offer-price">


        <span class="offer-buy-now   buy-now">
            <span class="statement">
                1 999,00 $


                    <span class="label">buy now</span>

            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
// many the same elements
```

Parse href and link value it's ok. But I have a problem to parse price. I get output with many whitespace and \n. I wants to show the same price with no `buy now`.

My sample output for prices

```
    2 497,00 $


        buy now




    2 379,00 $


        buy now
```

Code:

```
 request(task.url, function(err, resp, body){

                  if(body) {
                    $ = cheerio.load(body);
                    links = $('a.offer-title');
                    $(links).each(function (i, link) {

                      //console.log($(link).attr('href'));
                      var price = $('span.offer-buy-now').text();
                      console.log(price);
                      //items[k] = items[k] || [];
                      //items[k] = new itemParam($(link).text(), 12, k);
                      k++;

                    });

                  }
                  callback();
 });
```

How to fix it?

EDIT:

I correct foreach loop and it's works. But I have another problem. I not always get the answer with the data, only for 3,4,5 call gets results. Maybe there is something wrong with my request?

```
router.route('/send')
  .post(function(req, res){

      var url = req.body.url;
      var items = [];
      var k=0;
      var q = async.queue(function(task, callback){

            console.log(task.url);
            if(task.url.length>=1) {

              if (isURL(task.url)) {
                console.log('OK');


                request(task.url, function(err, resp, body){

                  if(body) {
                    $ = cheerio.load(body);
                    links = $('div.offer-info');

                    $(links).each(function (i, link) {

                      console.log($(link).find('a.offer-title').attr('href'));
                      var price = $(link).find('span.offer-buy-now').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
                      console.log(price);
                      items[k] = items[k] || [];
                      items[k] = new itemParam($(link).find('a.offer-title').text(),
                        price,$(link).find('a.offer-title').attr('href'), k);
                      k++;

                    });

                  }
                  callback();
                });

              } else {
                errorHandling(res, 401,"Invalid url");
              }
            }else{
                errorHandling(res, 401,"Invalid url");
            }

        }
      );


      q.push({url: url+'&p=1'});

      q.drain = function(errr, p) {
        console.log('all items have been processed' + items.length);
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {

          console.log(items[i].name + ' |  ' + items[i].id + ' | ' + items[i].price);

        }
        res.sendStatus(200);
      };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove buy now with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method then remove the white space with [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

```
links = $('a.offer-title');
$(links).each(function(i, link) {

  //console.log($(link).attr('href'));
  var price = $('span.offer-buy-now').text().replace('buy now', '').trim();
  console.log(price);
  //items[k] = items[k] || [];
  //items[k] = new itemParam($(link).text(), 12, k);
  k++;

});
```

**Other Solution**

or you can just remove every elements inside span `.statement` by `$('span.statement *').remove();` then you can get your `text`

Demo:

```js
links = $('a.offer-title');
$(links).each(function(i, link) {

  //console.log($(link).attr('href'));
  $('span.statement *').remove();
  var price = $('span.statement').text().trim();
  console.log(price);
  //items[k] = items[k] || [];
  //items[k] = new itemParam($(link).text(), 12, k);
  k++;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="offer-header">
  <a class="offer-title" href="http://address.com/id/2">Item name</a>
</h2>
<div class="offer-price">
  <span class="offer-buy-now   buy-now">
            <span class="statement">
                1 999,00 $


                    <span class="label">buy now</span>

  </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but I should reffer to `statement` by `$(link)` otherwise everything will show me a single line.

Comment: it return somthing or not ?

Comment: The same result, without replacing.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything from string except numbers using:

```
var price = $('span.offer-buy-now').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
```

**DEMO:**

```js
var str = "2 497,00 $         buy now";
strreplaced = str.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
alert(strreplaced);
```

Comment: @lukassz: i missed `g` identifier for regex. check now

Comment: @lukassz: do you want sum of all prices?

Comment: No I want to show one sum in one line. My `$(links).each` it's wrong I think.

Comment: @lukassz: create a fiddle with minimal code and reproducing problem.

Comment: I should reffer to statement by `$(link)` otherwise everything will show me a single line.